# Cat6A Runs in Hot Attic

Tags: networking, cable

I would like to make some significant upgrades to my home network which, right now, is comprised of a cable modem, wireless router, and a few wireless devices in various rooms. But wireless is nowhere near as fast as a wired connection, plus I'm adding some PoE cameras which will obviously require PoE. The hardware I need is pretty clear, but I'm concerned about running Ethernet cable in my attic considering that I live in Las Vegas, NV, which is EXTREMELY hot in the summer months (sometimes 115 degrees F). My assumption is that the attic probably exceeds the maximum operating temperature of most Ethernet cables (some are rated for up to 167 degrees F), but I don't actually know the precise temperature in the attic during the summer.

Given that Las Vegas is a modern city I can only presume that others have overcome this issue. Or maybe I'm overestimating the heat in my attic. My roof uses a light-colored terracotta tile, so I'm sure that's better than a black roof but don't really know. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use Plenum rated cable which is more heat tolerant, such as [L-Com bulk cable](https://www.l-com.com/ethernet-cat6a-f-utp-cmp-plenum-rated-high-temp-105-degree-28awg-4-pair-stranded-slim-line-blue-1kft), which tolerates up to 105 degrees Centigrade.

2) Add [solar powered soffit fans](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar%20powered%20soffit%20fans) to cool the attic space, which has the beneficial side effect of lowering your A/C cost.

3) Do both.

Comment: Thank you very much!! God I wish that cable wasn't SO EXPENSIVE, but I guess it would be a lot worse to go with cheap cable and wind up having to replace it.